# python: как дать название столбцам в диаграмме

Tags: python, matplotlib, анализ-данных

Нужно приравнять значения `result_1.values` к столбцам диаграммы
Мой код:

```
df_1['product_type'].value_counts()
print(result_1.values)

colors = ['red', 'violet', 'yellow', 'green']
x_data = [i for i in range(len(result_1.values))]
plt.bar(x_data, result_1.values,color=colors)
plt.xticks(x_data,result_1.keys(),rotation=0) 
plt.ylabel("Количество")
plt.show()`
```

получается вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то, не враз догадаешься. что вы используете *matplotlib*... Но, если моё предположение верно, то попробуйте добавить параметр

> tick_label: str, массив или optional ◦ Метки для столбца.

в вызов *plt.bar(..)*. Есть отличная книга: Абдрахманов М.И. "Python. Визуализация данных". Бесплатная !!! Издана devpractice.ru.  Там очень подробно всё расписано на странице 95.